# Capture SQL statements over Ethernet

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a device on the plant floor that I am looking to replace. This device is reading and writing to a SQL database that I have access to. I would like to know the read/write SQL statements the device is sending to the database.

Is there a way I can see these statements over Ethernet? I have the SQL Server Management Studio V17 installed.

Comment: Why do you need to do this on the network level? If you have admin access to the DB, you can use the profiler or system views like `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` and friends.

Comment: OK, I will look at those, thanks.

Comment: Wireshark ? Sounds a bit exaggerated though

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can see these statements over ethernet?

You can use [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) or the newer [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15) to capture all the queries sent to a SQL Server.

Comment: OK, I will look into this.  Thanks